Проблема увеличения длительности ответа запросов при установке Load Balancer на 2 сервера
У меня есть один основной сервер со стаком PHP8.2, MySQL8, Nginx (Ubuntu 22.04, Amazon Lightsail).
Технические характеристики сервера: 2 GB RAM, 2 vCPUs, 60 GB SSD.
Пик трафика в течение 4 часов — приблизительно 2.5 реквеста в секунду. Нагрузка на ЦП при этом пике 30-40%.
С целью снижения нагрузки на основном сервере было решено добавить второй сервер, который имеет такой же стак и технические характеристики, но обращается к основной БД через коннект по приватному IP-адресу в сети серверов Амазон.
Был настроен балансировщик нагрузки Cloudflare на один эндпоинт вида api.myproject.com с двух серверов.
При небольшой нагрузке на сервер всё работает нормально, но при большей нагрузке (в пик трафика) запросы на дополнительном сервере начинают отрабатывать по 5, 15, а иногда и 50 секунд.
Хотя если просто оставить основной сервер (без дополнительного) средняя стабильная скорость ответа эндпоинтов равна 100-200мс.
До настройки балансировщика был опробован HAProxy с использованием основного сервера как мастер-сервера, на котором был конфиг HAProxy — ситуация аналогичная, без каких-либо изменений.
В чём может быть причина такого поведения и как это можно решить?

2.5 запроса в секунду? не 250 и не 2.5тысячи? Не всегда проблемы надо решать путем увеличения вычислительных мощностей. Тут вероятно не в этом проблема. Как объем данных в БД соотносится в объемом памяти? Если вы там десятки гбайт баз хотите поднимать на 2ГБоперативки, то это конечно один вопрос. В технические характеристики чьи привели, пхп,  или базы, и нагрузка CPU на каких узлах?

прочитал еще раз. У вас первый сервер тащит все, и пхп и mysql,а второй дублирует пхп но обращется к первому за mysql. Тогда вопрос в силе. Какой объем данных вы пытаетесь обрабатывать на 2Гбайт памяти. Начните с профилирования запросов

Нужно профилировать и смотреть загруженность общего компонента - БД. Если у вас используются транзакции - тем более. Балансировка мало что даст если нагрузка не на веб-сервер, который делает много вычислений ...

Удвительно, как эта связка вообще поднимается и MySQL8 что-то обрабатывает на 2 Гб.
