Сервер на Ubuntu 18.04 падает из-за переполнения оперативной памяти
С серверной частью я не дружу. Прошу помочь
Работаю с проектом чуть больше полугода. На сервере стоит сайт на Laravel 5.1, база данных и почта. Посетителей менее 1.500 в день.
ПО сервера:

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-52-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Apache: 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.8
MySQL: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
PHP: 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

Характеристики сервера:

Процессор: 2 X Intel Core Processor (Broadwell)

Оперативная память: 2 GB

Дисковое пространство: 40 GB

Swap файл: 2 GB


Управление происходит через ispmanager lite v6.92.2
Ситуация:
На протяжение года сервер падал ~1 раз в 3 недели. Последний месяц он падал 1-2 раза в неделю, а последнюю неделю падает 1-2 раза в день. Происходит это в абсолютно рандомное время (может в 5 утра, а может в 4 вечера)
Падение происходит из-за загрузки оперативной памяти под максимум. Раньше с этим справлялся OOM-Killer за 15-20 минут
Предпринял увеличение Swap-file с 1 ГБ до 2 ГБ. После данной манипуляции, сервер стал падать и уже не мог подняться самостоятельно. Пришлось вручную перезагрузить сервер на хостинге (это не делалось больше года). В syslog перестали писаться действия OOM-Killer'a и изменились описываемые действия.
Всё это время не удавалось запечатлеть момент нагрузки и сегодня случайно заметил, что в один (случайный) момент возникает множество процессов php (каждый использует по 40МБ ОЗУ и их несколько десятков). Выяснить, что за php процессы запускаются и по какой причине не удаётся. Есть подозрения на ддос-атаки
Вопрос: Как я могу диагностировать, что вызывает эти процессы PHP, и какие дополнительные логи или информация могут помочь в решении проблемы?

А memory_limit в PHP какой?

Я бы дрбавил в скрипты логирование запуска и останова(в базейку бы писал старт/стоп), потом после падения проанализировал бы, что и как часто запускалось, останавливалось и что было открыто перед падением

Недавно был вопрос от энтузиаста, который похожий набор на 2 Гб пытался гонять. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596676

@Ипатьев В php.ini указана строка "memory_limit = 400M"

А ху-ху не хо-хо? В смысле не многовато ли? Почему бы не сделать хотя бы 128 например, а то и меньше? Тогда, глядишь, и сервер перестанет падать, а будет падать только пхп, причем указывая - в каком конкретно месте.

@Ипатьев попробую снизить. Спасибо за совет! Но это же ограничение 1 процесса php? Моя проблема была в их количестве. Каждый занимал по 40мб памяти, но их было около 20-30

Во-первых, вам надо прекратить падения всего сервера. Чтобы как раз таки "1 процесс РНР" и падал, а не весь сервер. Во-вторых, чтобы разобраться с количеством, надо получить ошибку PHP, в которой будет написано, в каком файле и в какой строке не хватило памяти. Может быть это никакой не "ддос", на который нерадивые администраторы списывают вообще все проблемы, а например сервер очередей.

@Ипатьев хорошо, спасибо!

@Ипатьев Добрый день, можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как решить проблему с тем, что OOM-Killer не запускается, когда память сервере забивается?

Без понятия. А главное, непонятно зачем. Если вы до сих пор не зарезали memory_limit для РНР, то я даже и не знаю что сказать. Продолжайте страдать
